# Убрать ненужные теги из bs4.element.Tag

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Доброй ночи друзья, пишу небольшой парсер:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import re

LINK = "https://premierliga.ru/tournaments/championship/tournament-table/"
def main():
    link = LINK
    print(get_data(get_html(link)))

def get_html(link):
    response = requests.get(link)
    return response.text

def get_data(html):

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
    trs = soup.find('div', class_=('stats-tournament- 
    table')).find('table').find_all('tr')
for tr in trs:
    position = tr.find('td', class_='place')
    print (position)
#return trs

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, парсер возвращает мне:

```
<td class="place">
  <span></span>1
        </td>
<td class="place">
  <span></span>2
        </td>
```

А я хочу получить только текст, в данном случае цифры между тегами, но у меня никак не получается. Пробовал воспользоваться get_text(), но пишет что нет такого атрибута, пробовал replace, результат тот же (видимо из за того, что это не строка), как можно отсюда вычленить только текст? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю насколько правильно так делать, `bs4.element.tag >` в строку, и так очищать. В целом проблема решена.

```
def get_data(html):

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
trs = soup.find('div', class_=('stats-tournament-table')).find('table').find_all('tr')
for tr in trs:
    position = tr.find('td', class_='place')
    position_str = re.sub('<[^>]+>',"",str(position))
    position_str = ''.join(position_str.split())#убираем перенос
    print(position_str)
#return trs
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый нижний цикл в листинге:

```
trs = bla_bla
for tr in trs:
    position = tr.find('td', {'class': 'place'})
    print (position.text.strip())
```

`<tag>.text` извлекает из тега текст целиком даже, если в нём есть вложенные теги со своим содержимым. Если все теги `class="place"` однотипные, с пустыми спанами, то вполне пойдёт и такой вариант. Функция `strip()` убирает пробельные символы по краям извлечённого текста.

Answer (score 0):

Правильней еще раз пройти в цикле:

```
def get_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
    trs = soup.find('div', class_=('stats-tournament-table')).find('table').find_all('tr')
    for tr in trs:
        position = tr.find_all('td', class_='place')
        for i in position:
            print (i.text.replace('\n', ''))
```